# selenium webdriver how to use object tag?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I need to click on a `pdf` file in the browser and the verify the contents in that,
By using below code am able to click on the `pdf` link but i can't verify the contents inside that `pdf` link ,the `pdf` is embedded in object.
How can we locate an element inside object tag and perform some actions on `pdf` file(`html` type).

To click on `pdf` link..

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='iconDock']/div/a[7]/img"));
element.click();
```

This code to verify content in pdf(its not working).

```
WebElement objectTag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[string(@id)='reportPanel']//object/html/body//div[@id=\"outerContainer\"]/div[@id=\"viewer\"]/div[@class=\"textLayer\"])"));
```

Help me out please

Answer (score 0):

you cannot verfiy the contents of the pdf using webdriver, u need to integrate with a tool called PDFBOX.Please find the link to give u basic understanding how to use it.

http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-extract-pdf-text-and-verify-using-selenium-webdriver-java

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot interact with a PDF, it is a library for driving a web browser.

The best advice is don't use WebDriver for downloading files.  Use it to get file locations and then use a different library to actually download files.

The easiest way to check a file is take an MD5/SHA1 hash of a known good copy of a file and then compare it with the MD5/SHA1 hash of the file you have downloaded.  It's how everybody checks that the file they have downloaded is correct.

More info in this blog post:

http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/